# Read checked items of CheckBoxList inside Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Maybe a stupid question but I need some help on how to read checkbox values inside a repeater when posting a form. I have a form and inside this form I have a Repeater and in each ItemTemplate I have a CheckBoxList. This is my code a little bit simplified:

```
<form method="post">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="FormInputValues">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="CheckBoxValues"
                DataSource='<%# ((FormOptions)Container.DataItem).Options %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="SelectorNext" CssClass="button" OnClick="SelectorNext_Click"
        Text="Next" runat="server" />
</form>
```

**My problem is that I need to be able to map all checked items in each CheckBoxList with its related data item.** Something like this:

```
Dictionary<"DataItem.ID", List<"CheckBox.Value">>
```

I can't figure out a good way to do this so if someone's got any suggestions I'll be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with the code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < FormInputValues.Items.Count; i++)
{
 CheckBoxList chklist = (CheckBoxList)FormInputValues.Items[i].FindControl("CheckBoxValues");
}
```

you will get every `CheckBoxList` in `chklist` object, you can traverse it to get selected checkboxes.

You can code like below to traverse `CheckBoxList`:

```
foreach (ListItem listItem in clbIncludes.Items)
{
    if (listItem.Selected) { 
    //do some work 
}
    else { 
    //do something else 
    }
}
```

where `clbIncludes` is a `CheckBoxList`

You can use `foreach` loop just inside the `for` loop to achieve your required thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Protected function repeater1_ItemCreated(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
      CheckBoxList checkBoxValues = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxValues");
      String selectedValue = checkBoxValues.SelectedValue;
      //Do your stuff ...
    }
}
```

**The ItemCreated event is the one you need, in there you can change how each repeater item looks.**

The other answer is also correct, but this example is more performant, as you do not need to loop through all repeater items and you do not need to loop through each checkbox in the `CheckBoxList`.